# how to enforce that Collection that contain only objects that implement a interface , but are from the same implementing class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

assuming there is an interface called Entity, there are many classes that implement it.
I need to create a class that for each instance of the class, its collection will contain only objects that implement the interface Entity, but are from **the same implementing class**, for example - if Person and Bicycle implement the interface Entity, then an instance of the class will have a collection full only with Person objects or Bicycle objects but not both. 
I appreciate your help!

Comment: `Collection<Person> theCollection` (resp. `Collection<Bicycle> ...`) !? Really, your question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: You can't via Java's type system (as in, you can't ensure that everything in the list is of an exact type, rather than subclasses of that type; but your design should not require you to). All you can do is to verify the types of the instances in the list at runtime.

Comment: You can declare a bounded type with multiple bounds (`<T extends Bicycle & Entity>`) but I don't really see the point. Could you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Something<T extends Entity> {
[...]
private Collection<T> entities;
```

`T` will always be one class implementing `Entity`. You can use `T` in all methods of this class.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, you could write your own add function and compare the class of the new Object with the class of the first Object in the collection. (If there is no Object in your collection yet just add it)

```
void add(Entity ent) {
    if (collection == null) {
        collection = new Collection<Entity>();
        collection.add(ent);
    }
    else if(ent.getClass().equals(collection.get(0).getClass()) {
        collection.add(ent);
    }
    else {
        // wrong class error handling here
   }
}
```

Something like that.